# Problem connecting RGBDSLAM + RViz

Tags: slam, navigation, rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I'm having problems connecting RGBDSLAM + Rviz in ubuntu 12.04. The main problem is that I don't have the topic needed to visualize the map that I'm creating with RGBDSLAM, it is supposed that I need:

/rgbdslam/transformed_slowdown_cloud

and

/rgbdslam/batch_clouds

and my topics about RGBDSLAM are the following:

/rgbdslam/aggregate_clouds
/rgbdslam/batch_clouds
/rgbdslam/correspondence_marker
/rgbdslam/parameter_descriptions
/rgbdslam/parameter_updates
/rgbdslam/pose_graph_markers

I don't have the "transformed_slowdown_cloud" in my topics, how could I create it? Have I to send a command in RGBDSLAM to create the topic?

Otherwise, I also noticed that adding a "pointcloud2" display, in the topics only appears 2 topics referring to RGBDSLAM: /rgbdslam/aggregate_clouds and /rgbdslam/batch_clouds. Is that ok? Should I see the rest of the topics?

Thanx in advance for your help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/61393/problem-connecting-rgbdslam-+-rviz/) by [dalogi84](https://answers.ros.org/users/4691/dalogi84/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2013-04-23

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2013-04-28**:
Why do you need the topic "/rgbdslam/transformed_slowdown_cloud"? I removed it some time ago.

**Comment by [dalogi84](https://answers.ros.org/users/4691/dalogi84/) on 2013-04-30**:
I needed it because I was following a tutorial about how to use Rviz with RGBDSLAM and it says I need that topic in order to see the world created with RGBDSLAM in RViz:

http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni/Contests/ROS%203D/RGBD-6D-SLAM

what topic can I use to see the world of RGBDSLAM in RViz? Thx

**Comment by [dalogi84](https://answers.ros.org/users/4691/dalogi84/) on 2013-05-03**:
I see...well I finally done it and now it is working! Thanx a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That is really old. You could use the batch_clouds topic and set the "decay time" high. I hope you use the version from ros.org/wiki/rgbdslam, not the one from the url you stated. The contest version is two years old.

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2013-05-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1